# Apply CSS to a singly word

Tags: html, css, styles

Is it possible to apply CSS in such a way that it will detect whenever there is a certain word in an element and mark that word up in some way? I know that I can add `<span style="...">word</span>` or `<span class="...">word</span>` inline with the HTML, but this won't automatically detect the word. Is there any way to do this entirely in CSS? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not really css has no real logic to it, the way you stated is really the only way to do it

Comment: You can do that with JavaScript, but there's no way to actually detect words by only using CSS. CSS is used to style elements, not anything else. But why do you want to do this by using CSS?

Comment: I wanted to make something that can automatically detect specific words and highlight them, sort of like syntax highlighting, and I want the site to be able to do this on its own so that a user can enter input and it will automatically detect which words to highlight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theres no way to do that in just css. You could replace all instances of the word with a wrapped version and apply a style as per your example http://jsfiddle.net/w9VbP/:

js

```
var word = 'hello';
var replacement = '<span class="theword">' + word + '</span>';

var re = new RegExp(word, 'ig');

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, replacement);
```

css

```
.theword
{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using jQuery. I am storing the html markup of body in `var text` and replacing `sample` with `<span class="change">sample1</span>` and putting back the updated html markup of the body.Obviously you will have to put this jQuery in the head section of the html as otherwise the `sample` string in the jQuery function will also be replaced with `<span class="change">sample1</span>`.

The jQuery function

```
$('body').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html().replace(/sample/g,'<span class="change">sample1</span>');
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

The Css:

```
.change{
color:red;
background:blue;
}
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thunderbird/hKHcP/2/)

Comment: Why use jQuery for this? Also .replace() will only replace the first instance of 'sample' : http://jsfiddle.net/u96pU/2/

Comment: @TomElmore fixed it. why not use jQuery?

Comment: because the only effect of using it is to add a dependency to your page and increase load times. the jquery is no simpler and no more readible - infact its almost identical apart from adding an extra 90k to download and calling 7 more functions than the straight JS.

Comment: i am a beginner to both javascript and jQuery and i find jQuery much more readable and simpler. 90k wouldnt effect your site performance at all. Even though i agree javascript here would be more efficient using Jquery wont effect your websites performance at all.